# Вопрос по ссылкам и объектам Java

Tags: java, memory

Здравствуйте. Что происходит с объектами созданными в методе. Вот пример:

```
public void example() {
Integer i = new Integer(4);
}
```

Здесь нам приспичило создать объект типа Integer, ок, но вот мы выполнили этот метод и что произойдёт после с этим объектом? Он просто удалится из stack'a и если на его нет больше ссылок кроме этой то и из heap'a?

```
public class Variables {
public static Variables variables = new Variables();
private ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
private Variables() {}
public ArrayList getArrList() {
return arrList;
}
}
public class Human {
private String name;
public Human(String name) {
this.name = name;
Variables.variables.getArrList().add(name);
}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}
public class Main() {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Human human = new Human("Josh");
//Теперь у нас переменная стринг "Josh" хранится и в коллекции и в поле объекта human и нам чтобы удалить этого Джоша надо удалить этот объект из коллекции Variables.variables.getArrList().remove(0); и присвоить Null human.setName(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выполнения метода объект удалится сборщиком мусора, поскольку на него нет ссылок, вот только когда именно это произойдет неизвестно. Вы не можете влиять на это процесс, но можете рекомендовать сборщику мусора удалить ненужные объекты, вместе с тем, он сам решит какие. Делается это просто - System.gc(). Но повторюсь, что это лишь рекомендация и гарантий, что этот объект удалится именно после вызова метода нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68556/discussion-on-answer-by--------java).

Answer (score 0):

Если напишите вот так, то будет другой смысл:

```
public void example() {
    Integer i = 4;
}
```

Потому что в этом случае будет создан не новый объект, а i будет присвоена ссылка на уже существующий объект из пула целых чисел. И сборщику мусора меньше работы

Comment: Т.е. объекта даже не существует как такового, ничего даже в heap отправляться не будет?

Comment: Объект существует - просто для некоторого пула чисел джава заранее делает объекты для ускорения работы, чтобы их не создавать в процессе работы программы. Т.е. эти объекты будут существовать "независимо" от вас. Пул можно настраивать. Но общий принцип - по возможности переиспользовать объекты для экономии времени и памяти.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понял, что у нас контролируемая по размерам куча, в обычном смысле этого слова, чисел и каждое по сути своей - это объект?

Comment: Давайте отделим мух от котлет. Пул чисел - это просто настраиваемое при запуске JVM некоторое количество объектов типа Integer которые создаются заранее для того чтобы была возможность быстро их переиспользовать, а не создавать. Вы можете не использоваьт эти объекты - а создавать свои  через оператор new - ваше право. Этот новый объект создается в куче, максимальный размер которой также можно установить при запуске JVM. Пул целых чисел и куча - это о разном.

Comment: т.е. допустимо создать пулы на миллиарды объектов Integer, лишь бы память хватило, но в действительности я не совсем понимаю как это работает. Мы создаём допустим пул на 1000 чисел объектов от -500 до 500 и лишь ради того, чтобы возможно сэкономить время на инициализации объектов?